# Issue with site header in firefox

Tags: html, css, wordpress, firefox

I've been working on a new theme for my wordpress website and after some tinkering everything looks and works fine except for my header.
When I open the website In firefox the header goes to It's full size and it ends up being too big while In other browsers It Is fine.

I've been googling solutions but none seem to work for me. Can anyone help me out so that firefox users won't get a big banner slapped in their faces?

Thanks In advance.

[Link to my website](http://sandbox.sallysubs.com/)

Comment: Please add the relevant source code to your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the float on the wrapping div.navbar-header. I don't know is max-width within a float is offspec, but just override bootstraps "float: left;" with "float: none;" from on the .navbar-header and you're good to go.

Comment: Good to hear. :) Accepting the answer would be nice then.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get rid of that `img {max-width:100%;}`  and replace it with a simple `width:100%;`